# Openshif: cron processing time?

Tags: openshift

I have read that openshift limits total processing time to 5 miniutes for a free account. Supposedly, this was/will be increased to 20 minutes.

Is it 5 or 20 minutes currently?

Is there a way to tell how much processing time you have used or have left?

These are daily limits, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing time is limited to 5 minutes per run.  So each time your script runs it has 5 minutes to run, you can try using the nohup command and run a sub-command to give it more time.

Comment: Ah. 5 minutes per run.  I asked the same question in the openshift forums about a month ago and nobody had an answer however someone said they were upping it to 20 minutes.  They posted the code change from the github repo. I will look into the cmds. Thanks